laravel 11 app fails on Custom VerifyCsrfToken middleware
I created a new laravel 11 app running on php 8.3.7 and i want to exclude some paths from csrf validation
after carefully reading the documentation https://laravel.com/docs/11.x/middleware#registering-middleware
i edited my app.php inside the bootstrap folder like this
<?php

use Illuminate\Foundation\Application;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Configuration\Exceptions;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Configuration\Middleware;

return Application::configure(basePath: dirname(__DIR__))
    ->withRouting(
        web: __DIR__ . '/../routes/web.php',
        commands: __DIR__ . '/../routes/console.php',
        health: '/up',
    )
    ->withMiddleware(function (Middleware $middleware) {
        $middleware->append([
            App\Http\Middleware\VerifyInstallation::class,
            Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Middleware\CheckForMaintenanceMode::class,
            App\Http\Middleware\TrimStrings::class,
            Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Middleware\ConvertEmptyStringsToNull::class,
            App\Http\Middleware\TrustProxies::class
        ]);

        $middleware->web(append: [
            App\Http\Middleware\SelectLanguage::class,
            App\Http\Middleware\CorsMiddleware::class,
            App\Http\Middleware\GameCdnMiddleware::class
        ]);

        $middleware->web(replace: [
            Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Middleware\VerifyCsrfToken::class =>App\Http\Middleware\CustomVerifyCsrfToken::class,
        ]);

        $middleware->api(append: [
            App\Http\Middleware\UseApiGuard::class,
            'throttle:60,1',
            'bindings'
        ]);


    })
    ->withExceptions(function (Exceptions $exceptions) {
        //
    })->create();

and my custom middleware
<?php
    namespace App\Http\Middleware {
        class CustomVerifyCsrfToken extends \Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Middleware\VerifyCsrfToken
        {
            protected $except = [
                '/profile/contact'
            ];
        }
    
    }

in debugger i noticed that the $except array is empty and my request returns 419,
i tried all the variations according to the documentation but non works, the middleware is invoked even if i dont specify it at all (by the way my route is specified in web.php)

You do not need to create a new middleware. In laravel 11, you can go to bootstrap/app.php and add URIs in except array.
$middleware->validateCsrfTokens(except: [
    'stripe/*',
    'http://example.com/foo/bar',
    'http://example.com/foo/*',
]);

Further detail can be found here.

well... that worked in an instance, thank you so much
